# AngularJS ui-mask for currency, max and min

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the official AngularJS UI-Mask https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask and trying to figure out how I can create a mask for currency USD.

So I can have the user type in $**.**. However, sometimes the input will exceed more than $99 dollars but the way I currently have it set it that it only goes to a set limit of how ever many I have set on the input.

How do I make it so I can make the mask work with larger whole numbers instead of the max being 99? I want the user to be able to put $00.01 to like $9,000,000.00 or whatever the desired max is.

Here is what I currently have: `<input type="text" ng-model="greeting" ui-mask="$99.99" class="form-control input-lg" style="width:50%" />`

Here is a live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ErV11uGVxJFmD24K2jk?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can get around the hard-coded ui-mask is setting it on scope.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="greeting" ui-mask="{{mask}}" 
  ng-change="updateMask() />
```

Then inside `updateMask()` you can determine how many characters are before/after the decimal and set it on $scope.mask.

Comment: I am not sure where you are going with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the "?" for optional chars

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-mask/master/demo/index.html